# How to create Arc with solid colour on Android background in Portrait and landscape

Tags: android, android-drawable

My current Android Application UI requires a two tone background with a curved arc as border as shown in the following image

[image]

I can achieve this effect in portrait (although I do not like using negative margin values) as follows...

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroud_arc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="-150dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-150dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background_circle" />
```

where background circle is this drawable shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/background" />
    <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="60dp" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="60dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="60dp" />
</shape>
```

Is there an easier method I can employ to achieve the desired effect?

In landscape this drawable is very badly "clipped".

Comment: You can use vector drawable for your desired designs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an inflexible drawable background, we should rather draw the colours along with the curve on the canvas.

For this we create a custom View `ArcBackgroundView` as below. The code is self explanatory:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Path
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

class ArcBackgroundView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs) {
    private val paint = Paint()
    private val path = Path()

    init {
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        if (canvas == null) {
            return
        }
        // Draw background color
        canvas.drawColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.blue))

        // Draw curve portion of background
        // Setup color
        paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white)

        val curveStartAndEndY = 0.6f * measuredHeight // <------ You can change this value based on your requirement
        // Set curve's control point's Y position (downwards bulge of curve) based on orientation
        var curveControlPointY = measuredHeight / 1.4f // <------ You can change this value based on your requirement
        if (resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            // Since in landscape mode, the curve will have greater arc length,
            // we need to give the curve more downwards bulge as compared to that in portrait mode.
            curveControlPointY = measuredHeight / 1.2f // <------ You can change this value based on your requirement
        }
        // Now we draw the entire path for curve
        path.moveTo(0f, curveStartAndEndY)
        path.quadTo(
            measuredWidth / 2f,
            curveControlPointY,
            measuredWidth.toFloat(),
            curveStartAndEndY
        )
        path.lineTo(measuredWidth.toFloat(), 0f)
        path.lineTo(0f, 0f)
        path.lineTo(0f, curveStartAndEndY)
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
    }
}
```

The `ArcBackgroundView` can now be used in an xml as shown below:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.myapp.ArcBackgroundView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The resulting output for Portrait and landscape is shown below:

[image]

[image]

Apart from creating a custom view as shown, if you require, you can also create a say custom `FrameLayout` called `ArcBackgroundFrameLayout`. Copy paste the code of onDraw() into your `ArcBackgroundFrameLayout's` `onDraw()`. Now you can use your custom container directly like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.myapp.ArcBackgroundFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="THIS IS A TEXT VIEW ON TOP OF THE DUAL TONE BACKGROUND"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</com.example.myapp.ArcBackgroundFrameLayout>
```

Note the `android:background="@color/black"` added with the `ArcBackgroundFrameLayout`. Some background (not necessarily black color) must be added otherwise for containers, #onDraw() would not be called. You should not worry about this black color as it would not show. We are changing background colours from inside our overridden `onDraw()`.

The resulting output for Portrait and landscape is shown below:

[image]

[image]

If you have any other requirement, please let me know. I will edit this answer.

The code is in Kotlin. If your project is in Java, please let me know again. I can edit and give a Java version of the same.

Thanks.